# Hard sittuation : how to set value "permission of user" into google sheets correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have "script A" that can list of any file in "source folder" with url 
Then i write "script B" to scan all ID of them and get every email user of file's permission, but when i set "email" value to [i] rows, it will overwrite till the last user of that permission.

Examples: if file "A" has 3 users of view, a@gmail, b@gmail, c@gmail, then "script B" will overwrite till c@gmail at file "A" row. (then we dont know about a@gmail, b@gmail have viewer permission.)

```
 function Listpermission() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataLength = getDataLength();  var data = getSheetValues();  
for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {   
  if(data[i]["Condition"] != "1") continue
var thisid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+1, 12).getValue()
Logger.log(thisid)
var editors = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getEditors()
for (var x = 0; x < editors.length;x++){
  var edit = editors[x].getEmail() }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+1, 14).setValue(edit)
var viewers = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getViewers()
for (var x = 0; x < viewers.length;x++) { 
  var view = viewers[x].getEmail()
   Logger.log(view)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+1, 13).setValue(view)

}}}
```

[This is log of runing script, in the red box, there are 2 user of view but it overwrite at: Range(i+1,13)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yX1u.png)

Any idea to solve this isue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve emails of editors and viewers from the file ID.

  - File IDs are in the column "L".
- You want to put the retrieved values to the cells.

  - From your script, I thought that you might want to put the values of editors and viewers to a cell, respectively.
  - You want to put the viewers and editors to the column "M" and "N", respectively.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about creating a value using `join()` and putting the value to the cells? For this situation, how about the following modifications? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script 1:

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the for loop is modified.

```
function Listpermission() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataLength = getDataLength();
  var data = getSheetValues();  
  for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    if (data[i]["Condition"] != "1") continue
    var thisid = ss.getRange(i+1, 12).getValue()
    var editors = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getEditors()
    var edit = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < editors.length;x++) {
      edit.push(editors[x].getEmail());
    }
    ss.getRange(i+1, 14).setValue(edit.join(","));
    var viewers = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getViewers();
    var view = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < viewers.length;x++) {
      view.push(viewers[x].getEmail());
    }
    ss.getRange(i+1, 13).setValue(view.join(","));
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the values are retrieved by `getValues()` and are created in the for loop and the created values are put to the Spreadsheet using `setValues()`. I think that this becomes lower cost of the process than that of `getValue()` and `setValue()`.

```
function Listpermission() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataLength = getDataLength();
  var data = getSheetValues();

  var thisids = ss.getRange(1, 12, dataLength, 1).getValues();
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < thisids.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]["Condition"] != "1") {
      values.push(["", ""]);
      continue;
    }
    var thisid = thisids[i][0];
    var view = [];
    var viewers = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getViewers();
    for (var x = 0; x < viewers.length;x++) {
      view.push(viewers[x].getEmail());
    }
    var edit = [];
    var editors = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getEditors();
    for (var x = 0; x < editors.length;x++) {
      edit.push(editors[x].getEmail());
    }
    values.push([view.join(","), edit.join(",")]);
  }
  ss.getRange(1, 13, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Your script work well and exactly what i need, amazing, thank you very much, hope this will help some other users. Best regards!

Comment: @Hung Cao Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I tested "Modified script 2": it work well and incredibly speed, but for more information, i scan both "FILE and FOLDER" in one spreadsheet, so i create a clone of " Modified script 2 "for listing folder permission and its result is pushing "blank space" to file's permission from previous time, is there a way for "Modified script 2" do list both FOLDER and FILE without over write blank space for each other.

Comment: with a script of JakubBoucek, i solved my problem but it cost too much energy to run, i prefer your "Modified script 2" but its too implicated for me to edit and add function listing Folder permission base on your original codes.

Comment: @Hung Cao From your 1st replying, I had thought that your issue was resolved. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `a way for "Modified script 2" do list both FOLDER and FILE without over write blank space for each other.`. Can you explain about the detail of it? I apologize for my poor English skill. If you can do, please update your question.

Comment: oh my. you are the most friendly, and kindest japanese friend i have ever met. I will give you detail information: 
1/ This spreadsheet have both link of FILE and FOLDER, and your "Modified script 2": it processes function to list permission of file very quickly with full of user in result. 
But when i create a copy of your script to do with "Folder", it run normally but the result is:  in the colum of "Viewer" it will eraser old data row, which i get from permission of Files, those are on the top of Folder row. So im just question you abt an updrage script to do with both File and Folder?

Comment: i solved my problem with @JakubBoucek 's script, but it take the final script too long to process with large number of files and folder, your script has better speed, but i can manage myself to use it to get folder's permission without erasing old data from file permission.... sr for my english also, kk

Comment: @Hung Cao Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still image your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this situation. So can you update your question by including the detail information? And also, I cannot understand about your Spreadsheet. So can you share it? At that time, please include the input and output you want. Of course, please remove your personal information. From thees information, I would like to try to think of the issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Fill array with all values to [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and then [join all values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to one column.

```
var viewers = DriveApp.getFileById(thisid).getViewers();
var viewerEmails = [];
for (var x = 0; x < viewers.length;x++) { 
  var view = viewers[x].getEmail();
  Logger.log(view);
  viewerEmails.push(view);
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+1, 13).setValue(viewerEmails.join());
```

Comment: your script work well, thank you for you help, have a good day with your work !